getting TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME]: The URL must be of scheme file in my React App created using Vite

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME]: The URL must be of scheme file
at fileURLToPath (node:internal/url:1489:11)

Upgraded to latest Node version and Vite latest version.
My Vite config file:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

import { ViteAliases } from "vite-aliases";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    ViteAliases({ prefix: "@", deep: false }), // Configure the plugin
  ],
});

I am also using jsconfig.json like below
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".", // Specifies the base directory for resolving non-relative module names.
        "paths": {
            "@assets/*": [
                "src/assets/*"
            ],
            "@components/*": [
                "src/components/*"
            ],
            "@/*": [
                "src/*"
            ],
            "@utils/*": [
                "src/utils/*"
            ],
            
            "@AddProject/*": [
                "src/components/AddProject/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}

Please find the package.json file:
{
  "name": "csr-ui",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@carbon/icons-react": "^11.50.1",
    "@carbon/react": "^1.67.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.2",
    "eslint": "^9.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "sass": "^1.79.5",
    "vite": "^5.4.9",
    "vite-aliases": "^0.11.7"
  }
}

